# Sql query join on not eqal

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have this relational model for hospital (not made by me).
Patient (has an adress and an id), hospital (has id and address), and also there's a table for relationship representing placement in the hospital (hospital.id, patient.id) (also there's other tables, but they don't matter in this query);
The purpose of the query is to find hospitals where is no placed patients from  from other cities than hospital's one (on condition that address only contains city).
The problem that i have is theoretical, i don't really know if to use full outer join with a or b null, or something else in the query that finds hospitals containing "foreign" patients, (like join hospital with its placement and then full outer join with a or b table record null, but that leads to a question will i get  results in the query? Because i need cities that **don't match** but all the explanations of that join are about .
Thanks to all who embraced my utterly imperfect english and understood it.
Upd.
Patient:

id=1, city =A;

id=2, city =B;

id=3, city =B;

id=4, city =A;

id=5, city =C;

Hospital:

Id =1, city=A

id =2, city=B;

Placement:

h.id p.id

1      1

1      4

2      2

2      3

2      5

Expected results is "1", id of the first hospital (where's no patients from other city) and others with that "feature"
my query is like

select id from hospital where id not in

(select id,address from hospital inner join placement on h.id=placement.h.id as b inner join patient on placement.p.id=p.id where hospital.address<>patient.address )
Sorry for the delay

Is shawn's query correct?
Can i use h.id instead 1? Idk if our teacher would accept that, because he's never showed us something like that and in 10 years he hasn't managed to create an example of that database for students to test queries on.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: No problem. But instead of a comment, edit your question.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken your desired result is the complement of relational division. Perhaps you'll find something relevant here: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Comment: What have you done???  Have you even tried anything???  Learn how ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Many thanks to shawnt for his help. Never meant to abuse someone's help, just tried to understand  possible implementations with three-table queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from hospitals h
where not exists (
    select 1 -- dummy value, use h.id if you prefer
    from patients p inner join placement pl on pl.pid = p.id
    where pl.hid = h.id and p.city <> h.city
)
```

or

```
select h.id
from hospitals h
    left outer join
    placement pl inner join patients p on p.id = pl.pid
        on pl.hid = h.id
group by h.id
-- this won't count nulls resulting from zero placements for that hospital
-- as long as standard sql null comparisons are active
having count(case when h.city <> p.city then 1 end) = 0
```

Looks like it works to me: http://rextester.com/BTJB59061